# Angular 8 - Input by reference

Tags: arrays, angular, input, reference

I don't understand this situation.
I have got a parent component that pass animals array to a child component

Parent:

```
export class Parent {
  animals: Animal[]=[{},{}];
}

<app-child [animals]="animals"></app-child>
```

Child:

```
export class Child {
  @Input()
  animals: Animal[];
}
```

I understand that it is passed by reference. When I try to clear animals array in my **child** component

```
this.animals=[];
```

then array in parent component doesn't change (It is not empty). Can someone explain me why?

Comment: How do you check it is not presented in parents array?

Comment: It works well for me https://ng-run.com/edit/sJc5sFkflUA33cLRxRyO

Comment: @hoo982 what is `animals.add`? You should use push.

Comment: @yurzui My mistake. You are right. It works. My aim is to clear this array from child component. For that purpose i used `this.animals=[]`. In that situation parents array stay the same. Have you got any idea why? I thought it is the same situation like described in Post but apparently it is not. Sorry for that.

Comment: That's because you're overriding reference not mutating it. You can use `this.animals.length = 0`

Comment: Use this method if yours doesn't work, this.animals.length = 0! Try to give specific questions and tags related to the questions. Initially, your question was based on arrays

Comment: if you want to mutate state use simple type instead complex. like use bool or number and check.

Comment: this.animals.length = 0 makes that my function works the way I wanted. Thank you for your help.